# ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK returning empty authToken in response?

Tags: ios, ocr, abbyy

I wanted an OCR solution for my project and I found ABBYY cloud OCR SDK interesting. I was just checking out a sample provided in the gitHub [link](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com#readme). The project requires an applicationID and a password to authenticate in their server. I got the required credentials by registering in their site as a free trial. The problem is that I cannot authenticate. I get an empty authToken as response.

It gets crash here

```
NSString *installationId = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"authToken"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:installationId forKey:kOCRSDKInstallationId]; 
NSParameterAssert(self.installationId);
```

These are from the sample project I used. I cannot figure out the reason for this. 
[image]

Its an exceptional breakpoint at **NSParameterAssert(self.installationId);**

I get this on crashing

> Assertion failure in -[OCRDemoClient
>   activateInstallationWithDeviceId:success:failure:force:],
>   /Users/meerajpai/Meera/OCR/ocrsdk.com-
>   master/iOS/Pods/OCRSDKClient/OCRSDKClient/OCRSDKClient.m:98

Close look at the screenshot is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63687661/Screen%20Shot.png)

Here is the response

```
Printing description of responseDictionary:
{
    "__name" = response;
    "_xmlns" = "http://ocrsdk.com/schema/response-1.0.xsd";
    "_xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    "_xsi:schemaLocation" = "http://ocrsdk.com/schema/response-1.0.xsd http://ocrsdk.com/schema/response-1.0.xsd";
    authToken =     {
    };
}
```

I am interested to know why cant I authenticate? Did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error it is showing...? can u post the contents of responseDictionary.

Comment: @Xman:Thanks for the reply.I have edited the question.Please check.

Comment: I think there is some problem with the authentication process at the server side, your credentials might not be correct or u might not have necessary rights to get authenticated. one more thing I noticed is the "authTocken" key...it should be in double quotes.

Comment: @Xman: I was asked to fill the applicationId and password which would be got by registering the application in their site. I did registered and got a mail from them with the credentials. And the application status is active in the site. I have double checked it. And that is why I am more curious!

Comment: @Xman: its the print description of response dictionary that I have pasted here

Comment: Do I have to be a paid user to get access to API and token??

Comment: According to this question in ABBYY Forum http://forum.ocrsdk.com/questions/1042/cant-find-application-id-abbyy_appid there is another hex value for applicationId which doesn't come in the email from ABBYY on registering the app. Its visible in the HTML content of the website. And on replacing this I don't get the crash instead I get 401 error. What is going wrong now? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because of an error in the sample code. It should be fixed this week, the temporary solution please see [in this post](http://forum.ocrsdk.com/questions/1114/authtoken-is-empty/1137).

Comment: I saw the issue. Actually I saw the gitHub page saying about this issue link - https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/issues/13 Its said there that for my application I don't require the authentication. I commented out that part so its working now. But I have one doubt, do we need auth token if I am using it on real project??